# Error while trying to create react app using npm

Tags: node.js, reactjs, create-react-app

I'm trying to creating react app using `create-react-app` command but I get this error message:

```
npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! errno ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! network Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/dotenv-expand: Socket timeout
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\IMAD\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-02-12T18_27_46_293Z-debug-0.log
```

I tried to clean cache:

```
npm cache clean -f
```

I also tried restarting the computer and reinstall nodejs and npm, but nothing was fixed.

Can anyone know what is the issue? and how can I solve it?

Comment: have you tried using vpn?

Comment: Did you read the message and ensure your proxy settings are correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more than 3 days of working on this error, I found the solution and fixed the problem by **install another version of Nodejs**.
The current version was **v16.14.0** when I got this error. And now it's **v16.0.0** and everything's is work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should use npx command (not npm) like that as in official documentation :  https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

Comment: Yes, I run the command with npx.

Comment: Maybe a problem of connection as it logged on npm error. Or you trying to create you project on protected directory ( try D:/ instread of  C:/)

Comment: My connection is fine, the project directory is on the desktop, I don't know what's wrong. I've been trying to fix it for two days, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Weird ! Could you try accessing this URL on your browser https://registry.npmjs.org/dotenv-expand

Comment: Could you also change the location of your project to D:/

Answer (score 0):

New versions of nodejs are not stable, downgrade to 16.0.0 was the better thing i made.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using the following command.

npm uninstall -g create-react-app

then

npm install -g create-react-app